# create a twig filter that wraps output in HTML

Tags: php, filter, twig, template-engine

I created a filter in Twig that wraps some HTML around the output. E.g.

```
{{ 'this is a "test"'|display }}
```

outputs

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    this is a "test"
  </div>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <a href="/edit.php">edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dilemma is, I would like that subsequent filters are applied only on the original content, and not on the entire html. E.g.

```
{{ 'this is a "test"'|display|upper|e }}
```

outputs

```
&LT;DIV ID=&QUOT;CONTAINER&QUOT;&GT;
  &LT;DIV ID=&QUOT;CONTENT&QUOT;&GT;
    THIS IS A &QUOT;TEST&QUOT;
  &LT;/DIV&GT;
  &LT;DIV ID=&QUOT;TOOLBAR&QUOT;&GT;
    &LT;A HREF=&QUOT;/EDIT.PHP&QUOT;&GT;EDIT&LT;/A&GT;
  &LT;/DIV&GT;
&LT;/DIV&GT;
```

but as you can imagine, I would prefer the output like this

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    THIS IS A &QUOT;TEST&QUOT;
  </div>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <a href="/edit.php">edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changing the filter order to

```
{{ 'this is a "test"'|upper|e|display }}
```

would work for the upper filter, but not for the escape filter, because it places itself always at the end of the filter queue. Also it should work with autoescape=true.

Reading the twig documentation, I can't find a standard way to do what I want. Has someone maybe tried something similar? Or has someone an idea to work around the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ 'this is a "test"'|upper|e|display }}
```

Filter your content in first place and then wrap it.

Comment: thanks. The problem is that the e filter is an exception and places itself always at the end of the filter queue. I would also like the function working with autoescape=true.

Comment: OMG, SF2 is still amazing me... Then try making your own escaping filter, but you will have to use it explicitly I don't think SF2 will let you change it's autoescaping method as far as I read.

Comment: That's an idea. I will look into that. Atlthough I can imagine that it is all but trivial.